# как нарисовать незамкнутую кривую в inkscape

Tags: inkscape

Вопрос примитивный и обусловлен какой-то кривизной установки или "счастливой звездой".

Пытаюсь начать работать с inkscape и встрял чуть ли не на первом шаге: нарисовать линию.
Выбираю инструмент "Рисовать кривые Безье и прямые линии", режимы сверху выбираю то кривые Безье, то "последовательность прямых отрезков", неважно, клацаю левой кнопкой мыши, рисуется набор последовательных отрезков и ... я хочу их завершить. Нажимаю Enter, либо двойной клик мышки, либо любую другую кнопку на клавиатуре, всегда происходит замыкание контура и образование объекта (path в слое) залитый выбранным цветом заливки.

а мне нужна линия.

и хоть тресни, не могу найти какую-то волшебную галочку, которая приводит к этому замыканию.
прочитал уже двадцать туториалов на разных сайтах, в том числе и на самом inkscape, нигде об этом ничего не говорится. у всех чудесным образом линия всегда остаётся линией, а если хочешь замкнуть, то должен последнюю точку поставить в первую. а у меня она всегда замыкается, куда не ткни.

прошу открыть мне глаза на очевидную промашку.

версия inkscape 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Вроде не было такой проблемы.

Завершение кривой двойным кликом или ПКМ. Нужно чтоб заливка стояла в режиме *Нет* (редактор позволяет заливать незамкнутые контуры).

Завершение замкнутого контура по клику на первой точке.

Но пока воркэраунд (если точки реально замыкаются всегда)

Инструментом редактирования узлов (второй на панельке) выдели первый и последний узлы и нажми кнопку разорвать контур на панельке действий.

Comment: к сожалению, не выходит.
установил тот же дистрибутив на другом компе, проблема аналогичная.
рисую линии, получаю замкнутую фигуру (кстати, в параметре "фигура" указано "нет"). выбираю инструмент редактирования узлов, выделяю два узла и жму "разорвать контур в выделенных узлах" - ничего не происходит. выделяю три узла и жму разорвать - разрывается фигура, но вместо линии я получаю посечённую на части фигуру

Answer (score 0):

В свежеустановленном Inkscape надо перейти: Правка --> Параметры --> Инструменты --> Перо, здесь "Стиль новых объектов" включить "Собственным стилем инструмента". Проверено в Inkscape 1.2 (Linux).